# Unresponsive desktop, but almost nothing else?

Tags: windows-7, windows

OS: Windows 7 64-bit
My desktop icons are frozen all of a sudden. I can't click on anything, I can't select anything, etc. BUT it is only my desktop. All of my programs runs perfectly fine. This goes away whenever I restart, or log off, then back on, but returns after like 5 minutes. Has anyone else had this issue before? I think that LogMeIn Hamachi or Skype may be the culprit but im not sure.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desktop is shown by the explorer.exe process. Have a look at your running process (press the start button and type in: taskmgr for taskmanager) and also the eventlogs (press the start button and type in: eventvwr).

If there's something that needs too much resources and causes explorer to hang, you will probably see it in taskmanager. If there's something wrong with an application, there may be an error in the application eventlog.

Once you found the problem you should un- or reinstall the problem application if it's third party. If it's the explorer itself, you could try to run windows repair.

If you found errors in your eventlogs but you don't know how to proceed, post screenshots of them here.

Comment: Task manager says explorer.ese is using 60,000 k of memory, and its CPU usage is usually at 00 and occationally goes to 1 2 3 4 or 5 really quick, but mostly its at 0 is this normal?

Comment: I'm currently at a Linux box, but I think that's normal. What do the eventlogs tell you? Any application crashes or errors?

Comment: I didnt find anything that had Windows Explorer, Skype, or Hamachi thats recent that looks bad, but I found alot of Kernel Event Tracing errors, I'm posting a picture right now...

Comment: in task manager, i ended Internet Explorer, and the problem mostly went away, but it never did this before even when I had dozens of tabs open, so i think something else might be related to it as well

Comment: have a look at your application logs. These are under "Windows Logs". If you find anything in there, please double click on those events and post a screenshot of the detailed event.
You could also start IE without addons (I think, the shortcut to IE w/o addons is somewhere in the accessories) and then deactivate all addons that aren't necessary.

Comment: I didn't find anything there that looked bad either, and the problem still happened even though i disabled add-ons, it took longer to happen, but its still there. I've noticed in task manager that their are 3 processes named iexplore.exe and one has about 150,000 k memory usage, one has 62,000 k, and one has 12,000 k

Comment: in your events there is an application hang event at 10:22:08 PM. please open that event by double clicking on it and post a screenshot here. have you already checked for viruses?

Comment: ok i posted it.

Comment: ok, look into the other messages. if they're all about skype not interacting with windows, reinstall skype. please check also if the skype toolbar is installed (add/remove programs in control panel) and uninstall it. the toolbar isn't needed by skype.

Comment: I uninstalled Skype and its toolbar and it works fine now. I don't know which one was the problem because i uninstalled both before I tried IE again...thanks